# Loop through matching elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a repeater control which contains a panel. I want to loop through the panels in the repeater and hide them based on an input parameter using jQuery.

```
function ShowInfo(ctrlShow) {    
            jQuery("div[id*='_pnlInfo_']").each(function (index, value) {
               if(jQuery(this).attr('id').toLower() != ctrlShow.toLower())
                    jQuery(this).hide();
            });
            jQuery(ctrlShow).slideToggle(800);
        }
```

But it throws the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What value are you passing in as `ctrlShow`?

Comment: The ClientID of one of the panels I want to display.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `console.log(ctrlShow)` or `alert(ctrlShow)` to check that it is not `undefined`. 

Also, exactly which line is the TypeError coming from.

Comment: The ctrlShow is being passed alright. The error is thrown on the line if(jQuery(this).attr('id').toLower() != ctrlShow.toLower())

Comment: Are you attaching the pound sign to `ctrlShow`? jQuery requires the  id to be prefixed with `#`. For example, `$('#id')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You migth use a different approach, by excluding the specific element from your selector like this:

```
function showInfo(ctrlShow){
    $("div[id*='_pnlInfo_']").not("#" + ctrlShow).hide();
    $("#" + ctrlShow).slideToggle(800);
}
```